# libCURL: Crash on Uploading Data (Qt, SMTP)

Tags: c++, qt, email, smtp, libcurl

i am trying to implement a quite specialized email-client using libcurl (7.66) for sending the email.

Sadly, it always crashes on calling curl_easy_perform(curl), no matter what i try whatsoever.

Currently in the process_mail callback i have commented everything out; just returning 0. I am pretty shure, this should be enough for at least not crasing the app ...

The real goal would be having the mail as a string in the memory and just copy it over to the stream.

I really appreciate any kind of help ... i have quite a delay because of this issue.

Here is the header-file:

```
#ifndef MAILMESSAGE_H
#define MAILMESSAGE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QByteArray>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class MailMessage : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MailMessage(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void setSMTPPort(QString smtp_port);
    void setSMTPAddress(QString smtp_address);
    void setSMTPUser(QString smtp_user);
    void setSMTPPassword(QString smtp_password);

    void addTo(QString address_to);
    void setFrom(QString address_from);
    void setSubject(QString subject);

    void setAlternativeText(QString text);
    void setHTML(QString html);
    void addAttachment(QString attachment_path, QString filename);

    void generateMessage();
    // return POSIX-style: 0: ok; 1: error
    int sendMail();

    QString message;
    int message_size;
    const char* message_char;

    QString smtp_port;
    QString smtp_address;
    QString smtp_user;
    QString smtp_password;
    //QStringList addresses_to;
    QString address_to;
    QString address_from;
    QString subject;
    QString payload_text;
    QString payload_html;
    QStringList attachments_base64;

    double upload_speed;
    double upload_time;

protected:
    static size_t process_mail(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MAILMESSAGE_H
```

And the relevant parts of the implementation:

```
void MailMessage::generateMessage()
{
    this->message = //"To: "+ this->address_to +"\r\n"
            "From: "+ this->address_from +"\r\n"
            "Subject: "+ this->subject +"\r\n"
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=MixedBoundary"
            "\r\n"
            "--MixedBoundary"
            "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=AlternativeBoundary"
            "\r\n"
            "--AlternativeBoundary"
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\""
            "\r\n"+ this->payload_text +"\r\n"
            "--AlternativeBoundary"
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\""
            "\r\n"+ this->payload_html +"\r\n"
            "--AlternativeBoundary--"
            "\r\n"
            "--MixedBoundary";
    /*
            "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"HelloWorld.pdf\""
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"HelloWorld.pdf\"";
    */
    this->message.append("\r\n"
            "--MixedBoundary--");

    QByteArray array = this->message.toLocal8Bit();
    this->message_char = array.data();
    this->message_size = sizeof(this->message_char);
}

size_t MailMessage::process_mail(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userprocess)
{
    size_t retcode = 0;

    /*
    MailMessage *self = reinterpret_cast<MailMessage*>(userprocess);

    if (sizeof(self->message_char) == 0)
        return retcode;

    retcode = (size * nmemb >= sizeof(self->message_char)) ? sizeof(self->message_char) : size * nmemb;


    self->message_size -= retcode;
    memcpy(ptr, self->message_char, retcode);
    self->message_char += retcode;
    */

    return retcode;
}

int MailMessage::sendMail()
{
    //qDebug() << this->message;

    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    // CURLUSESSL_ALL, CURLUSESSL_NONE, CURLUSESSL_TRY, CURLUSESSL_CONTROL
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, this->smtp_address.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, this->smtp_user.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, this->smtp_password.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, this->address_from.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, this->address_to.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, &MailMessage::process_mail);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, this);

    /* Send the message */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    else
    {
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &upload_speed);
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &upload_time);

        qDebug() << "Speed: "+QString::number(upload_speed) + " Time: "+QString::number(upload_time);
    }

    //curl_slist_free_all(this->address_to.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

And finally some excerpt of the console output:

```
*  start date: May  8 08:01:21 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May 13 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mail.gmx.net" matched cert's "mail.gmx.net"
*  issuer: C=DE; O=T-Systems International GmbH; OU=T-Systems Trust Center; ST=Nordrhein Westfalen; postalCode=57250; L=Netphen; street=Untere Industriestr. 20; CN=TeleSec ServerPass Extended Validation Class 3 CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> EHLO cf-19
* SMTP 0x5572580cd700 state change from UPGRADETLS to EHLO
< 250-gmx.com Hello cf-19 [2.202.204.204]
* Curl_pp_readresp_ 55 bytes of trailing server response left
< 250-8BITMIME* Curl_pp_readresp_ 41 bytes of trailing server response left
< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
* Curl_pp_readresp_ 19 bytes of trailing server response left
< 250 SIZE 69920427
> AUTH PLAIN
* SASL 0x5572580cd780 state change from STOP to PLAIN
* SMTP 0x5572580cd700 state change from EHLO to AUTH
< 334 
> AHNhbXVlbF9iZWNrZXJAZ214LmRlADI4OTZhY2Q2
* SASL 0x5572580cd780 state change from PLAIN to FINAL
< 235 Authentication succeeded
* SASL 0x5572580cd780 state change from FINAL to STOP
* SMTP 0x5572580cd700 state change from AUTH to STOP
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x5572580d0678; line 1701 (connection #0)
* DO phase starts
> MAIL FROM:<xxxxxxx@xxx.xx>
* SMTP 0x5572580cd700 state change from STOP to MAIL
* STATE: DO => DOING handle 0x5572580d0678; line 1743 (connection #0)
< 250 Requested mail action okay, completed
03:37:55: The program has unexpectedly finished.
03:37:55: The process was ended forcefully.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. so regarding "no matter what i try whatsoever", could you show us what did you try? Edit your post, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
QByteArray array = this->message.toLocal8Bit();
```

This creates a local `QByteArray` object, a local variable in the `generateMessage()` method. When `generateMessage()` returns, this object and everything in it will, of course, be destroyed just like any other function local variable. That's how local function variables work in C++.

```
this->message_char = array.data();
this->message_size = sizeof(this->message_char);
```

This saves a pointer to `array`'s internal buffer in `message_char`. This also saves `sizeof(this->message_char)` in `message_size`. Since `message_char` is a `const char *`, this will always save `sizeof(const char *)`, which will typically be 4 or 8 (depending on your operating system), in `message_size`, no matter how big the `array` is. That's already an obvious fail at this point, but not the ultimate fail that crashes the shown code.

The ultimate fail is that, as I've explained earlier, as soon as this function returns -- which is right about now (since this is the last statement in this function) -- `array` and all of its contents gets immediately destroyed. The aforementioned pointer to `array`'s internal buffer will become a dangling pointer, to the internal contents of an object that no longer exists, and any further attempts to dereference this pointer results in undefined behavior, and a likely crash.

This is the obvious reason for your crash: improper usage of dangling pointers to destroyed objects. Additionally contributory factor is improper usage of `sizeof` (in the event your message's actual size happens to be less than the size of a pointer on your operating system).

Comment: So i changed sizeof to strlen and declared the variable storing the result of this->message.toLocal8Bit(); as a class-variable in the header-file. It still crashes. The debugger clearly shows the crashing line to be curl_easy_perform.

Comment: What i do not understand is, why the wrongly used pointer to a deleted objetc leads to a crash even though none of these pointers were used afterwards (as everything in process_mail is commented out, except of returning 0)

Comment: These are the only defects that were obvious from the limited amount of the shown code. Because your code example fails to meet the requirements of a [mre], making it impossible for anyone else to reproduce your crash, and analyze it, there's little additional information that anyone else could possibly tell you. For more information, see [ask] questions, in the [help]. Just because the crash occurs in the part of the code that calls this library function doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in your code, which is why an [mre] is required.